# How to save stl container in disk?

Tags: c++, serialization, stl

I have a stl container, which save a lot of data.

for example, the definition is:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int32_t> > m;  // there are 10 million data in this container
```

what i want is to save it in a file, then next time, i can read this file to recover it quickly.

i think the normal way, like:

```
write(&m, sizeof(m))
```

doesn't work, because it only save the pointer.

so, how can i save it in file and recover it by read file?

Comment: [Boost.Serialisation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)?

Comment: c++ has no out-of the box serialization. You either need to do it yourself, or use a library.

Comment: @Evg that's great, but install boost may add external library, i may need a independent way to do that

Comment: Then the only option is to do it by hand, recursively, element by element.

Comment: @Evg s/recursively/iteratively/

Comment: @rustyx I don't know how one can *iterate* over nestedness of containers.

Comment: Anything that can be done with recursion can be done with iteration. Nested, like nested loops?

Comment: @sweenish By nested containers I mean something like `A<B<C<int>>>`, see the question body. There is no clear and simple way to iterate over such containers in a generic way without recursion. Obviously, I'm not talking about using recursion to iterate over `std::vector` elements.

Comment: Yes there is. With nested loops. Like I said.

Comment: @sweenish In a **generic** way. You'll have to write custom nested loops for each container. Using recursion and templates you can write just one piece of code to handle all combinations of nested containers. Whether OP needs a generic solution is a different question.

Comment: @sweenish Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/GbKa6K A compiler can optimize away all recursive calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a file format, e.g. a simple list, iterate over your container and write each element:

```
for (const auto &el : m) {
    file << el.first << '\n' << el.second.size() << '\n';
    for (const auto &vecEl : el.second) {
        file << vecEl << '\n';
    }
}
```

Then you can read the file with

```
std::string first;
std::size_t count;
while (std::getline(file, first) && file >> count) {
    std::vector<int32_t> v(count);
    for (auto &vecEl : v) {
        file >> vecEl;
    }
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    m[first] = v;
}
```

This is just a sketch. You probably have to add error checks.

Comment: thanks jabaa, it's a good way, but i think it may be not fast. save in a binary format, and read it out may be a good way, i am reading to find if this can be ok

Answer (score 1):

Given you're not keen to use boost, the lowest-effort lowest-reusability option is something like:

```
// some support macros for easy error detection/handling...

#define FATAL(MSG) \
    do { \
         std::cerr << "FATAL ERROR at line " << __LINE__ << ":\n" \
             "    " << MSG << '\n'; \
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    } while (false)

#define ASSERT(X, MSG) \
     do { \
         if (X) break; \
         FATAL("ASSERT(" #X ") FAILED; " << MSG); \
     } while (false)

// output your container to disk...

if (std::ofstream out{filename}) {
    for (auto& [key, value] : m) {
        out << key.size() << ' ';
        out.write(key.data(), key.size();
        out << ' ' << value.size();
        for (auto& i : values)
            out << ' ' << i;
        out >> '\n';
    }
    ASSERT(out, "failed while writing to " << filename);
}
else
    FATAL("failed to create " << filename);
```

This just creates a file with lines like:

```
13 A 13 char str 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

The leading 13 means you know how many characters are in the string before parsing it, which saves us the trouble of coming up with some escaping and terminator convention, or the risk of not having one (e.g. assuming the string doesn't embed a newline is risky in general).  The first '5' indicates the array length, only needed to speed loading, as it lets you reserve enough memory up front, which may be faster than  using `.push_back` and having to `resize` during loading of an array.

Reading the file then becomes:

```
if (std::ifstream in{filename}) {
    size_t len;
    while (in >> len) {
        std::string key;
        key.resize(len);
        ASSERT(in.read(key.data(), len));
        ASSERT(in >> len);
        std::vector<int32_t> v;
        v.reserve(len);
        while (len--) {
            ASSERT(in >> num);
            v.push_back(num);
        }
    }
    ASSERT(out.eof(), "failed to parse string size");
    m[std::move(key)] = std::move(v);
}
else
    FATAL("failed to open " << filename);
```

I haven't tested this, so use/test/debug as needed....